# Can't set nofill() when using PGraphics

Tags: processing

I Can't set noFill while rendering to a PGraphics object.
Trying to draw an arc gets me this.

[image: Wrong result]

While what i want is this.

[image: Correct result]

I used the following code in the processing application for 64 bit windows 7

```
PGraphics pg;
void setup() {
  size(123, 123);
  pg = createGraphics(123, 123);
  pg.strokeWeight(5);
  pg.stroke(255);
  pg.noFill();
  noFill();
}

void draw() {
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);
  pg.translate(width/2, height/2);

  pg.arc(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, PI+1);

  pg.endDraw();
  image(pg, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to set modes and style for `PG` inside draw block and it works like you want:

```
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);

  pg.strokeWeight(5);
  pg.stroke(255);
  pg.noFill();
  pg.translate(width/2, height/2);

  pg.arc(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, PI+1);

  pg.endDraw();
```

Comment: Thanks, the inconsistency confused me.

Comment: Yes it could be confusing but [beginDraw](https://www.processing.org/reference/PGraphics_beginDraw_.html) set default properties for this object so you need to reset them.